# How to fill the textbox background color using Python-pptx?

Tags: python, textbox, python-pptx

I am using Python-pptx to create ppt, i want to fill the textbox background with other color.

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Inches, Pt
from datetime import datetime
from pptx.dml.color import RGBColor
from pptx.enum.text import PP_ALIGN

prs = Presentation()
prs.slide_width = Inches(16)
prs.slide_height = Inches(9)
blank_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[6]
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(blank_slide_layout)

slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[5]
slide2 = prs.slides.add_slide(slide_layout)

title_textbox = slide.shapes.add_textbox(Inches(5), Inches(0.4), Inches(6), Inches(0.6))
title = title_textbox.text_frame

pic = slide.shapes.add_picture('image_name.jpg', Inches(3.8), Inches(1.3), Inches(8.5), Inches(6))

subtitle_textbox = slide.shapes.add_textbox(Inches(5), Inches(7.5), Inches(6), Inches(1))
subtitle = subtitle_textbox.text_frame
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if I got your question correctly. You want to create a textbox and color it?

I changed it a bit:

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Inches
from pptx.dml.color import RGBColor

prs = Presentation()
prs.slide_width = Inches(16)
prs.slide_height = Inches(9)
blank_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[6]
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(blank_slide_layout)

textbox = slide.shapes.add_textbox(Inches(5), Inches(0.4), Inches(6), Inches(5))

textbox.text_frame.text = "foo"
textbox.fill.solid()
textbox.fill.fore_color.rgb = RGBColor(255, 0, 0)
```

This creates a textbox with text "foo" and red color. You can find more options for the manipulation of your shape [here](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/shapes.html#pptx.shapes.autoshape.Shape).